# Problems compiling typescript files

Tags: typescript

I am just learning how to use typescript and I am having problems getting my files to to compile correctly into Javascript files. I am on windows and I am using Visual Studio Code. My tsconfig.json file is as follows:

```
    {
       "compilerOptions": {
       "target": "ES5",
       "noImplicitAny": true,
       "removeComments": true,
       "preserveConstEnums": true,
       "out": "output/project.js",
       "sourceMap": true
    },
       "files": [
       "hello-world.ts"
      ]
    }
```

My hello-world.ts file is:

```
    class Startup {  
    public static main():number{
          console.log('hello world');
          return 1;
        }
    }
```

And Finally the .vscode/tasks.json file is as follows:

```
    {
       "version": "0.1.0",
       "command": "tsc",
       "showOutput": "always",
       "isShellCommand": true,
       "args": [],
       "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
    }
```

When I click ctrl+shift+b it shows that it is working on compiling the file but it does not ever create it. Any ideas I what I should check to get the file to compile correctly?

Comment: all the settings seem ok.. Does it work when you invoke `tsc` from commandline? Maybe you don't have `tsc` in the `PATH`?

Comment: If I run tsc from command line it does work. I don't believe that I have tsc in the path. However I can't find an example of what it should be.

Comment: Didn't you install tsc globally?

Comment: @Chris if `tsc` runs OK from command line, then it's in the PATH - that's ok.

Comment: you could try and break `tsconfig.json` (so it isn't a valid json) to see if `tsc` is even running from VS Code - you should see an error message in the Output window.

Comment: @qbik The problem was simply that it was missing out of the PATH. I did find a blog post on fixing the problem here: http://updatestage.com/fix-wrong-typescript-compiler-version/